# How to stop collection view receiving scroll events

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Below is my view heirarchy. Here Overlay view is added as subview to collectionView with user interaction disabled. When tried to do scroll the collection view receives the events but they don't receive tap events. How do I stop collection view receiving these scroll events? Is there any way overlay view stops sending those events?

```
-View
  *collectionView
     *overlayview
```

I tried disabling user interaction in overlay view still collection view receives the scroll events.